# Postfix - Bounced e-mail in mailq for non-exist email account

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, email-bounces, queue

My postfix mail queue has quite a few bounced back e-mails; however, the recipient of the bounced back e-mail does not exist, e.g. `@server_hostname.example.local`, so it will never be delivered and nobody would know that the message was bounced back. What I'd like to do is redirect these bounced back emails to a department's shared e-mail so that the department is aware of the bounce back. I was wondering what's the best way to do this? I've tried a couple of options but they don't seem to work for me. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: What exactly is in your mail queue? What exactly is in the mail _log_?

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

1. `echo "@server_hostname.example.local spam.magnet@org.com" >> /etc/postfix/canonical`
2. `postmap /etc/postfix/canonical`

Though this has the side-effect of re-writing the destination email address to `spam.magnet@org.com`.

refs:

- http://www.postfix.org/canonical.5.html
- http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html

You might also want to look at [2bounce_notice_recipient](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#2bounce_notice_recipient) but I've not actually tried using that one yet.